# Increase the "width" of ghci

Tags: haskell, ghci

When an output line is too long in GHCI, it is broken:

```
> :i bar
bar :: Lens' (Foo a0) Int   -- Defined at NewType_makeLenses.hs:7:1
> :i baz
baz :: Lens (Foo a0) (Foo a1) a0 a1
    -- Defined at NewType_makeLenses.hs:7:1
```

Is there a way to set the maximal length of the lines?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are three options that control [pretty printing:](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/flags.html)

```
-dppr-debug         Turn on debug printing (more verbose)
-dppr-user-length   Set the depth for printing expressions in error msgs    
-dppr-cols⟨N⟩       Set the width of debugging output. For example -dppr-cols200
```

You're looking for `-dppr-cols`. Its default value is `100`. You can set it to any other value, either when you call GHCi or with `:set`.

## Comparison of the the options

### Without `-dppr-cols`

```
$ ghci NewType_makeLenses.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( NewType_makeLenses.hs, interpreted )  
Ok, modules loaded: Main.                                                   
> :i bar                                                                    
bar :: Lens' (Foo a0) Int       -- Defined at NewType_makeLenses.hs:9:1     
> :i baz                                                                    
baz :: Lens (Foo a0) (Foo a1) a0 a1                                         
        -- Defined at NewType_makeLenses.hs:10:1
```

### With `-dppr-cols140`

```
$ ghci -dppr-cols140 NewType_makeLenses.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( NewType_makeLenses.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
> :i bar
bar :: Lens' (Foo a0) Int       -- Defined at NewType_makeLenses.hs:9:1
> :i baz
baz :: Lens (Foo a0) (Foo a1) a0 a1     -- Defined at NewType_makeLenses.hs:10:1
```

### With `:set -dppr-cols140`

```
$ ghci NewType_makeLenses.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( NewType_makeLenses.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
> :set -dppr-cols140
> :i bar
bar :: Lens' (Foo a0) Int       -- Defined at NewType_makeLenses.hs:9:1
> :i baz
baz :: Lens (Foo a0) (Foo a1) a0 a1     -- Defined at NewType_makeLenses.hs:10:1
```

## Bonus: how did I find this?

I didn't look into the flags, instead, I looked into GHC's source code:

```
$ git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/ghc/ghc.git && cd ghc
```

Next, I look for a string that starts with `"Defined`:

```
$ grep -C2 "\"Defined" -r . --exclude-dir=testsuite
./compiler/basicTypes/Name.hs-ppr_z_occ_name occ = ztext (zEncodeFS (occNameFS occ))
./compiler/basicTypes/Name.hs-
./compiler/basicTypes/Name.hs:-- Prints (if mod information is available) "Defined at <loc>" or
./compiler/basicTypes/Name.hs:--  "Defined in <mod>" information for a Name.
./compiler/basicTypes/Name.hs-pprDefinedAt :: Name -> SDoc
./compiler/basicTypes/Name.hs:pprDefinedAt name = text "Defined" <+> pprNameDefnLoc name
./compiler/basicTypes/Name.hs-
./compiler/basicTypes/Name.hs-pprNameDefnLoc :: Name -> SDoc
```

`SDoc` seems interesting.

```
$ grep "data SDoc" -r . --exclude-dir=testsuite
./compiler/utils/Outputable.hs:data SDocContext = SDC
./compiler/utils/Outputable.hs-boot:data SDoc
```

`Outputable.hs` includes `printForUser`, which uses `pprCol dflags` together with `printDoc` from `Pretty`. `printDoc` is defined as

```
printDoc :: Mode -> Int -> Handle -> Doc -> IO ()
-- printDoc adds a newline to the end
printDoc mode cols hdl doc = printDoc_ mode cols hdl (doc $$ text "")
```

and `pprCol` is defined in `compiler/main/DynFlags.hs`, where it corresponds to `-dppr-cols`. You can just `grep` your way through GHC :).

Comment: Thanks. I've included this option in my [ghcitohtml](https://github.com/stla/ghcitohtml) tool :)